# How to format history file to contain username too?

Tags: bashrc

```
tail -2 /root/.bashrc
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
export PROMPT_COMMAND='builtin history 1 >> /var/log/root.log'
```

With this all the commands could be logged (even the ones that were in "[sudo su -](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108577/how-to-log-commands-within-a-sudo-su)" ).

**My question**: How can I put username info in the history file, so not just the time will be logged, but the original user, who "sudo su -"'ed username is in the history files too (or process PID from it's shell, or any unique identifier)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start a `root` `bash` shell as `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` or `sudo su` (provided `root`'s login shell is `bash`) or `sudo bash`, the original user is available as `$SUDO_USER`.

But when started as `sudo su -`, the environment is cleared by `su`, so you'll have to find another way to find the original user.

One way, if you've got the `pstree` command could be:

```
original_user=${SUDO_USER:-$(pstree -Alsu "$$" |
  sed -n "s/.*(\([^)]*\)).*($USER)[^(]*$/\1/p")}
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="<%F %T> (${original_user:-$USER}) [$$] "
export PROMPT_COMMAND='builtin history 1 >> /var/log/root.log'
```

The idea being to parse the output of `pstree -Alsu "$$"` which looks like:

```
init---xterm(user)---zsh---sudo(root)---su---bash---pstree
```

To extract the `user`.

Comment: great solution, thanks! i use even `original_user=$(pstree -Alsu "$$" | sed -n "s/^[^\(]*(\([^)]*\)).*($USER)[^(]*$/\1/p")` - in case s/b makes `sudo -iu <user>` several times

Answer (score 1):

<del>You can't</del> You might be able to hack something, see @StephaneChazelas's answer below.

The shell's history file is user specific. The `sudo` commands will be listed in your actual user's history. If you use `sudo su -` you are opening a new shell where you are logged in as `root`. Any commands run there will be in `root`'s history file but there is no way of knowing who your user was before since that is in a completely different shell.

By the way, using `sudo su -` is completely pointless. Either use `su -` or, `sudo -i` both of which have the same result.