# $LIB variable does not expand to anything in Ubuntu Server 18.10

Tags: debian, dynamic-linking, elf, dynamic-loading

I have the same exact problem as this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155438/ld-so-preload-doesnt-differ-x86-32-and-x86-64) previously posted, where `/etc/ld.so.preload` does not intercept the right architecture. A little background: I have compiled a shared object (64-bit) that is referenced in the `ld.so.preload` file on any binary execution. The problem was that I was getting a `ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/mysharedobject.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.` when executing 32-bit programs.

To fix the issue according to the answer in that question, I had to make two directories (`lib/i386-linux-gnu` and `x86_64-linux-gnu`, for example, in `/var/opt`) and specify `/var/opt/$LIB/mysharedobject.so` in `/etc/ld.so.preload` so the right library will be preloaded depending in program architecture.

So in that case, in Debian based systems, `/var/opt/$LIB/mysharedobject.so` would expand to:

- `/var/opt/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mysharedobject.so` for 32-bit programs;
- `/var/opt/x86_64-linux-gnu/mysharedobject.so` for 64-bit programs.

However, after applying this, any binary I run (such as `ls`) will output the following 'error':
`ERROR: ld.so: object '/var/opt/$LIB/mysharedobject.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`

As you can see, $LIB did not expand to anything. I have also set `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/var/opt` and ran `ldconfig` to update the system with this libs, but with no success. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the problem.`$LIB` environment variable expands to `lib32` directory for 32-bit programs and `lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` for 64-bit programs (as `/usr/$LIB/mysharedlibrary.so` in `/etc/ld.so.preload`) - as shown in `strace`. This is for Debian based systems, as for other systems it will expand to `lib64` and `lib` (could always confirm with `strace`, more specifically the `openat()` system call).

So the solution would be to compile the shared library with both `-m32` and `-m64` and put the relevant architecture files to their respective referenced folders from `$LIB`.

In summary (example):

```
$ mkdir {32,64}
$ gcc -Wall -m32 -fPIC -shared -o 32/mysharedlibrary.so mysharedlibrary.c -ldl
$ gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o 64/mysharedlibrary.so mysharedlibrary.c -ldl
$ sudo mv 32/mysharedlibrary.so /usr/lib32/mysharedlibrary.so
$ sudo mv 64/mysharedlibrary.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mysharedlibrary.so
$ sudo echo '/usr/$LIB/mysharedlibrary.so' > /etc/ld.so.preload
```

Answer (score 1):

The ***shell*** would expand **`$LIB`**, but it was not possible when you did this:

> specify **`/var/opt/$LIB/mysharedobject.so`** in **`/etc/ld.so.preload`**

The [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) mentioning **`/etc/ld.so.preload`** doesn't mention the possibility of glob-expansions or environment variables:

> File containing a whitespace-separated list of ELF shared
>   objects to be loaded before the program.  See the discussion
>   of **`LD_PRELOAD`** above.  If both **`LD_PRELOAD`** and
>   ***`/etc/ld.so.preload`*** are employed, the libraries specified by
>   **`LD_PRELOAD`** are preloaded first.  **`/etc/ld.so.preload`** has a
>   system-wide effect, causing the specified libraries to be
>   preloaded for all programs that are executed on the system.
>   (This is usually undesirable, and is typically employed only
>   as an emergency remedy, for example, as a temporary workaround
>   to a library misconfiguration issue.)

nor would that be likely, when you stop to think about how the data is used:

- glob-expansions would be a security problem, since the data (being inexplicit) could match all sorts of interesting files, and
- environment variables would have to be set ***somewhere***, and would easily differ for different users.

Now... the manual page mentions that **`$LIB`** can be used in rpath and `LD_PRELOAD`, but it also says

> In secure-execution mode, preload pathnames containing slashes
>   are ignored.  *Furthermore, shared objects are preloaded only
>   from the standard search directories and only if they have
>   set-user-ID mode bit enabled (which is not typical).*

That's one pitfall which would affect you since **`/var/opt`** probably isn't a *standard search* directory.

Comment: Apparently, the `$LIB` was being expanded but it was only shown in `strace` rather than the 'error' message: `lib32` directory for 32-bit programs and `lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` for 64-bit programs (as `/usr/$LIB/mysharedobject.so` in `/etc/ld.so.preload`)

Comment: strace might also show an error message (a failed open/openat) for the library, though not the actual cause if the machine is running in secure-execution mode.