# History of commands run by user after logging into root

Tags: suse, linux-audit

I have a requirement to audit all the commands run by a user after he logs into root. Can anyone please help me with it. (for Suse-Linux)

To explain even more simpler

1. user alex logs into the server with his username and password
2. switches to root user, runs few commands (I want to know what commands were run by Alex after switching into root user) if possible with timestamps

Comment: What shell is alex running ? How does he runs priviledged commands su ? sudo ? sudo su... ?

Comment: @MC68020 bash shell

Comment: WRT to the duplicate, the accepted answer is not available in Suse where it is in Ubuntu however [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109495/20140) should be compatible.

Comment: @MC68020 Alex uses a bash shell and uses sudo su - to switch to root